# Manually adjust alignment for text

Tags: symbols, vertical-alignment

I have an equation where it contains a `\bigtriangledown`, and the resulting equation looks like this:

[image: alignment]

I was wondering if there was a way to adjust the `\bigtriangledown` so it looks more inline with the rest of the equation, maybe something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: why you not use for this vector equation more correct symbol `\nabla`? (try to loudly read this equation ...)

Comment: Turns out that that was much better, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this vector equation is correct symbol `\nabla`:

[image]

(we read this equation something as "scalar product of nabla and magnetic field B is equal ... ", but are you sure that equation is correct? 3th Maxwel equation is slightly different)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[active,displaymath, tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\[
\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B}=\frac{4\pi}{c}\vec{J} + \frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}
\]
\end{document}
```